# Using Namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I have a "Web Project" in VS.
File structure

```
- AdminCms
  - Sections
    - CmsAuthors
- App_Code
  - Business Logics
    - Common
       - BuilderStrings.cs
    - DataAccess
      -CmsModel.edmx
```

When I Build the Project VS in BIN Create a Cms.dll file.

In file "BuilderStrings.cs" I use:

```
namespace Cms.App_Code.BusinessLogics.Common
```

Using this code from folder "CmsAuthors"

```
using Cms.App_Code.BusinessLogics.Common;
```

As so far all is working fine.

Now for my understanding I should be able to name the namespace as I want ex:

```
namescape Wdg.Cms.Common
```

so if I use:

```
using Wdg.Cms.Common;
```

Script should be work just fine. **Instead I get an error "Missing Assembly Reference".**

- What is wrong?
- It is namespae a sort of path how to retrieve the Class?
- Why I cannot use a different name?

Thanks guys for you help!

Comment: Apparently there's no error(but for the use of "namesCaPe" instead of namesPaCe, but i think it's just a typo) are you sure the error comes from that namespace? can you provide any more information?

Comment: Error is Missing Assembly Reference, YES I think is the user of namespace, infact if i use the automatic name version it works. if I changed with my custom name it does not? any ideas? Can i change the name of namespace without change the structure of files? I use VS as WEB PROJECT..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine. Have you **saved** and **rebuild** your project?

** I did get the error for the first time as I didn't save my changes in app_code.

1. Nothing wrong here.
2. The main purpose of having namespace is to avoid class name collision. For example, you have StringBuilder.cs in App_Code/Admin and App_Code/Common, you can differentiate them by using name space: `Wdg.Cms.Common.StringBuilder` and `Wdg.Cms.Admin.StringBuilder`
3. You can use a different name.

Comment: Hi Lee, I understand your point, and I was thinking the same, but when I change the name for namespace I receive the same error. All my code has been BUILD as CMS.DLL..... is for this reason that I cannot use anywhere else a custom namespace Wdg.Cms.Common???? thanks for now!

Comment: HI lee, sorry did you test it as WEB PROJECT or WEB SITE in VS? thanks

Comment: I tested it as Web Site in VS

Answer (score 1):

namespaces should be defined using conventions, according to Microsoft "*The general rule for naming namespaces is to use the company name followed by the technology name and optionally the feature and design as follows*: CompanyName.TechnologyName[.Feature][.Design]
". 
Have a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28VS.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229002

http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your namespaces the same throughout your solution.  You've used Cms.App_Code.BusinessLogics.Common in several places, so continue to use that in all places.

Your usage of Wdg.Cms.Common may be the cause of your Missing Assembly error.

Comment: Thanks Lane, sorry but my questions is WHY I CANNOT give the name scape as I want?? looks like more a FILE PATH.. thansk for your time